# Power set in Scheme with ordered output

Tags: sorting, scheme

So I am familiar with the algorithm for creating a power set using Scheme that looks something like this:

```
 (define (power-set set) 
    (if (null? set) '(()) 
       (let ((power-set-of-rest (power-set (cdr set)))) 
             (append power-set-of-rest 
                   (map (lambda (subset) (cons (car set) subset)) 
                         power-set-of-rest)))))
```

So this, for (1, 2, 3, 4), would output:

```
(() (4) (3) (3 4) (2) (2 4) (2 3) (2 3 4) (1) (1 4) (1 3) (1 3 4) (1 2) (1 2 4) 
 (1 2 3) (1 2 3 4))
```

I need to figure out how to output the power set "in order", for example:

```
(() (1) (2) (3) (4) (1 2) (1 3) (1 4) (2 3) (2 4) (3 4) (1 2 3) (1 2 4) (1 3 4) 
(2 3 4) (1 2 3 4))
```

Doing a little research, it seems as if the best option would be for me to run a sort before outputting. I am NOT allowed to use built in sorts, so I have found some example sorts for sorting a list:

```
(define (qsort e)
  (if (or (null? e) (<= (length e) 1)) 
    e
    (let loop ((left  null)    (right null)
               (pivot (car e)) (rest  (cdr e)))
      (if (null? rest)
         (append (append (qsort left) (list pivot)) (qsort right))
         (if (<= (car rest) pivot)
            (loop (append left (list (car rest))) right pivot (cdr rest))
            (loop left (append right (list (car rest))) pivot (cdr rest)))))))
```

I cannot figure out how I would go about sorting it based off of the second, or third element in one of the power sets though. Can anyone provide an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a compare function that should work for your needs. It assumes that the numbers in the two input arguments are sorted already.

```
(define (list-less? lst1 lst2)

  ;; Compare the contents of the lists.
  (define (helper l1 l2)

    ;; If two lists are identical, the answer is false.
    ;; This scenario won't be exercised in the problem.
    ;; It's here only for the sake of completeness.
    (if (null? l1)
      #f

      ;; If the first item of the second list is greater than
      ;; the first item, return true.
      (if (> (car l2) (car l1))
        #t
        (or (< (car l1) (car l2)) (helper (cdr l1) (cdr l2))))))

  ;; First compare the lengths of the input arguments.
  ;; A list of smaller length are assumed to be "less"
  ;; than list of greater length.
  ;; Only when the lists are of equal length, do we
  ;; compare the contents of the lists.
  (let ((len1 (length lst1)) (len2 (length lst2)))
    (if (> len1 len2)
      #f
      (or (< len1 len2) (helper lst1 lst2)))))
```

Comment: To clarify, I would have to have my own function in order to look through the full power set and swap lists on a case-by-case basis?

Comment: @elykl33t that is correct. Looking at your code, I assumed you have worked out the logic of `qsort`. The function I provided only helps with comparing two items from the power set.

Comment: Within the qsort function, I keep getting an error "null: undefined;
 cannot reference undefined identifier". I am using Racket. Any advice?

Comment: Using comparing to achieve proper ordering is no good as the set's elements can be non-comparable. You *could* do it with *decorate-sort-undecorate*....

Comment: @WillNess what do you mean? Sorry, I am fairly new to functional programming. How is it that I could use my power-set function in conjunction with list-less and qsort to implement the desired behavior?

Comment: it worked for you because your set's elements are numbers, that you could compare with `<`. But the groupings of elements into subsets shouldn't depend at all on what kind of elements your set holds. You could of course index your elements by increasing numbers, and compare the indexed bundles by their index values, then recover the original items (throwing away the indices). See ["Schwartzian transform"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform).

Answer (score 2):

Here's a `powerset` function that returns the items in the correct order, without sorting. It requires Racket and uses its queues to implement breadth-first processing:

```
(require srfi/1 data/queue)
(define (powerset items)
  (define fifo (make-queue))
  (enqueue! fifo (cons '() items))
  (let loop ((result '()))
    (if (queue-empty? fifo)
        (reverse result)
        (let* ((head-entry (dequeue! fifo))
               (subset     (car head-entry))
               (rest-items (cdr head-entry)))
          (pair-for-each (lambda (next-items)
                           (enqueue! fifo (cons (cons (car next-items) subset)
                                                (cdr next-items))))
                         rest-items)
          (loop (cons (reverse subset) result))))))
```

We maintain a FIFO queue of pairs, each consisting of a subset (in reversed order) and a list of items not included in it, starting with an empty subset so all the original items are still not included in it.

For each such pair, we collect the subset into the result list, and also extend the queue by extending this subset by each item from the not-included items. Processing stops when the queue is empty.

Because we extend subsets each time by one element only, and in order, the result is ordered too.

Comment: I noticed this answer got downvoted... I still haven't voted here, because of the lack of comments or explanations...  Your code isn't self-explanatory for sure. :) Maybe that's what ticked off the silent downvoter.

Comment: @WillNess Thanks for your support! I thought the snippet was pretty self-explanatory, but I'll explain it here. Each queue item is a cons cell, of which the `car` is what to prepend, and the `cdr` is the remaining items to iterate through. (You'll notice that my `(cons (car x) item)` suggests that it's not being prepended, but notice the `reverse` at the end.)