# Lazy list of binary number with k one

Tags: list, haskell, binary, lazy-evaluation

How would one implement a list of list with **k** *one* and **0** *zero*, lists with **k-1** *one* and **1** *zero*, ... , list with **0** *one* and **k** *zero* in Haskell so that they could be retrieved lazily?

For example if **k**=3:

```
generate_list 3 = [[1,1,1],[0,1,1],[1,0,1],[1,1,0],[0,0,1],[0,1,0],[1,0,0],[0,0,0]]
```

Thanks [bheklilr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/839246/bheklilr) for advices. Here is my solution:

```
generate k = take (2^k) $ foldl (\x y -> zipWith (:) y x) (map (\x->[x]) (head rows)) (tail rows)
      where 
            rows = map cycle $ map pattern [0..k-1]
            pattern i = replicate (2^i) 1 ++ replicate (2^i) 0
```

But there is a problem:

```
generate_list 3 = [[1,1,1], [0,1,1], [1,0,1], [1,1,0], [0,0,1], [0,1,0], [1,0,0], [0,0,0]]
generate 3 = [[1,1,1], [1,1,0], [1,0,1], [1,0,0], [0,1,1], [0,1,0], [0,0,1], [0,0,0]]

generate 3 !! 3 = [1,0,0] - it contains 1 one
generate_list 3 !! 3 = [1,1,0] - it contain 2 one
```

So for my task order in `generate_list` output order is important and `[1,1,0]` must precede `[1,0,0]`.

Comment: What have you attempted so far?  Can you show any code you've attempted, or even say what libraries you've tried to use, like `Data.List`?

Comment: Have you thought about the relationship this would have with building a [truth table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table)?  There's a very simple algorithm for filling one out by hand, how might you turn that into code?

Comment: I'd like to generate list reversed. If I build a truth table and reverse it, I'll lose laziness.

Comment: What if you build the truth table reversed to start with?

Comment: I have a solution that does it in the correct order (not the actual order you have, since `[0, 1, 1]` should come after `[1, 1, 0]`, `[1, 0, 0]`, and `[1, 0, 1]` logically), and I have confirmed that it does so lazily.  However, you still have not shown any of your own attempts.  Can you edit your question with an attempt, even if it doesn't compile?  Stackoverflow is not a forum to get answers for free, but for help when you get stuck.

Comment: cf. http://stackoverflow.com/a/23255303/849891.

Answer (score 1):

Using some functions from `Data.List`, this is pretty easily solved.  I will point out that your function should likely be producing

```
[[1,1,1], [1,1,0], [1,0,1], [1,0,0], [0,1,1], [0,1,0], [0,0,1], [0,0,0]]
```

instead, which follows a pattern and a natural ordering.

There are two parts to this problem, generating lists of alternating 1s and 0s with a certain number of repeats (i.e. `[0, 1, 0, 1, ..]`, `[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, ..]`, etc), then joining them together correctly.

For the first problem, the `replicate` function is very handy.  You can easily generate the base pattern with

```
replicate (2^i) 0 ++ replicate (2^i) 1
```

Where `2^i` is the number of repeating digits, so for `i = 0`, this would output `[0, 1]`, and for `i = 3`, it would output `[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]`.

There is a function in `Data.List` that will turn this base pattern into an infinite stream, repeating itself over and over, you'll have to find it yourself (hint: it has the type signature `[a] -> [a]`, and [hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle)).  Since that function generates an infinite list, you'll have to trim it down to size with `take ???`, where `???` is the length to trim to.  With this, you should be able to generate each column of a [truth table], but starting with 0s, while you want it to start with 1s.  Can you figure out how to generate them 1s first?

Now that you have a snippet of code to generate each column you'll need a function to "zip" each column together, but the built-in `zip` functions won't work here since they only operate on a specific number of lists at a time.  Is there another function you could use that can be described as an n-way zip?

This should get you started, but there are several gaps to fill in yourself.  If you get stuck again, just comment and say what you got stuck on, but you really should be solving this problem yourself as much as you can.

Answer (score 1):

> How would one implement a list of list with k one and 0 zero, lists with k-1 one and 1 zero, ... , list with 0 one and k zero in Haskell so that they could be retrieved lazily?

Write a function that creates a list of lists with `m` ones and `n` zeros. Then call this function `k` times (with `k` and `0`, then with `k-1` and `1`, etc.) and `++` the results.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using applicative functors.

```
generate 0 = [[]]
generate k = (:) <$> [1,0] <*> generate (k-1)
```

I wonder how to show that this is indeed lazy?

Comment: It is, and you can easily verify this in GHCi with `let x = generate 3`, then `take 3 x`, then `:print x`.  You should see an output like `x = [1,1,1] : [1,1,0] : [1,0,1] : (_t1::[[Integer]])`, which tells you that it only compute the first three elements of `x`.

Comment: Thanks for the `:print` command! I didn't know such thing existed.

Comment: This is not maximally lazy, however.  `head (generate (10^8))` takes a very long time.  There is a way to solve this so it responds immediately no matter how large the input, left as an exercise ;-)